# Executing many queries in one transaction

Tags: haskell, sqlite

I'm porting a parser + SQLite data importer as my first project in Haskell, and I need some help in getting into how one is supposed to do things re monads.
I'm using parsec for the parsing part, and then a conversion function that pits out SQLite queries that would do the job of inserting the data into the database.

Now, because of it using a parsec parser, the type of the resulting data is :

```
IO (Either ParseError [(String, [SqlValue])])
```

This is a sample of the data

```
Right ("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO utterances 
(id,name,filelength,updated_at,checksum_algorithm, checksum) VALUES (ifnull(NULL, 
(select id from utterances where name = ?)) , ? ,?, datetime(),'MD5',?);",[SqlString 
"testdata/testdata.TextGrid",SqlString "testdata/testdata.TextGrid",SqlDouble 
1.0,SqlString "FAKE"])
```

Now, I need to run the queries in a single transaction, but how do I do this when the data is in an IO ( Either x a)) package?

Like I said, I am very new to Haskell, so I appreciate all the help I can get here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "trick" with monads is to have each operation live as deeply inside of the computation as possible. For instance, let's say we have

```
result :: IO (Either ParseError [(String, [SqlValue])])
```

then we can write

```
liftM go result
```

so that `go` only needs to process something of type `Either ParseError [(String, [SqlValue])]` and can ignore `IO`. We can go deeper.

```
liftM (liftM makeQuery) result
```

would be where we could put a `makeQuery :: [(String, [SqlValue])] -> SqlQuery` builder which creates the query we want to send to the database. This is a pure function that would be very easy to test on its own, say in a unit test where we build the `[(String, [SqlValue])]` bit by hand.

We can move between layers by unwrapping. Each monadic layer has its own style of unwrapping. For instance, we can unwrap an `Either` by matching it with `case`

```
do either <- result   -- use do notation to look inside of the IO layer
   case either of
     Left parseError -> putStrLn (show parseError)     -- convert the error to some IO
     Right insides -> sendQuery db (makeQuery insides) -- send our built query
```

Again, by reaching into the inner layers of our Monad we get to write simpler functions. For instance, here the fictitious `sendQuery` has type `DBConnection -> SqlQuery -> IO ()`, i.e. it just sends `SqlQueries` however they might arrive. This has very strong single responsibility principle design.

There's a lot of complexity remaining in the goal you've set for yourself, but handling monads essentially comes down to those two tools--work in layers and isolate your actions. I'd try to build functions which (1) take a SQL database action and wrap it in a transaction (the type might look like `withTransaction :: IO () -> IO ()` because it upgrades an `IO` action to be inside a transaction) (2) build queries like `makeQuery` does above (3) handle errors gracefully like I was doing with `show parseError` though that's clearly a hacky solution, and (4) isolates your parsing into a single place.

Comment: `print` composes `putStrLn` and `show`, so you could change `putStrLn (show parseError)` to `print parseError`.

Comment: Yep, just being a bit more explicit.